# Hazelcast management center on kuberntes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, hazelcast

How can we run the Hazelcast management center on Kubernetes?
What i did so far is - Deployed the hazelcast/management-center Docker image on our Kubernetes cluster. However as seen on the management-center Pod log, it has started on localhost:8080 by default. I did this with a 'Deployment' on K8s pointing to Docker hazelcast/management-center image. Hazelcast Server is running as the Spring Boot application, also other applications are able to connect to this as Hazelcast client.

Question is how can we run/connect the management center to our Hazelcast cluster running on the same namespace in the Kubernetes (with 2 members in the cluster)?

Comment: Hello @getSantsoh. Could you please share your yaml configs by editing the question?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [official helm chart](https://github.com/hazelcast/charts), it includes Management Center by default.

If it doesn't work for you, first I would check if there is a k8s Service defined for the deployment, and if yes, if there is a k8s Ingress exposing that service.

Comment: Is it necessary / required to use helm?
I currently have Deployment, Service and Ingress (similar to all other apps in our project including Hazelcast Server). Where i use image=hazelcast/management-center
and when pod comes up it by default shows running on http://localhost:8080/

So even though i have opened up the service port and ingress rule it doent connect to the management center Pod.

Comment: It isn't necessary, but you can look into how Management Center is deployed, that may help with your problem: https://github.com/hazelcast/charts/tree/master/stable/hazelcast/templates